# Understand memory allocation for python numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, memory-leaks

I'd like to wrap my head around the memory allocation behavior in python numpy array. The question is as below:

What happen when a smaller array replace a bigger array size in terms of the memory used? Example as below:

```
[1] arr = np.rand.randint(1, 10, size=(2000, 3000)
...
[100] arr = np.ran.randint(1, 10, size=(20, 30)
```

At line `[100]`, the size of the `arr` object will decrease corresponding to its reduced size. SO two things i like to know:

1. Are the areas bigger than that of `(20, 30)` new size will still be inside the pc memory as a garbage memory?
2. If above is true, do I need to explicitly use `del arr` before line `[100]`?

---

Footnote: the main reason for my question is i am writing a large python program mainly based on numpy. And this is my first time writing a program for use with large dataset (normal size would be 50k rows, 7 columns).

I found that every time I rerun the program, the memory keep increasing, instead of what i expect it to be back to original again since i am replacing all the variables (mem keep increasing even after i explicitly write `gc.collect()` in many lines and also write some `del` for my variables).

My suspicion for now is maybe the bigger array when replace with smaller array, the memory is still inside ram, just not being mapped (my question above).

It would be helpful too if i you have any comment on what i can do on this memory leak problem. Tq

Answer (score 0):

The assignment at [100] creates a new array object, and assigns it to variable `arr`.  If there aren't any other references to the object originally assigned to `arr` (at [1]), then that object will be available for garbage collecting.  Temporarily the large and small arrays will exist in memory at the same time.

The space used by [1] might be reused within the Python/numpy session, or might be released to the OS.

Don't forget that numpy objects consists of a small block with shape, dtype info, and large block of `data buffer`.  `views` can share the data buffer.  That complicates the task of identifying whether the memory will be reclaimed.

Usually with `numpy`, and Python in general, we don't `del` an object.  We don't try to control memory that finely.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by `rerun the program`.  Do you mean some sort of loop in a given Python session, or a new call to the script from a shell?

Comment: `rerun the program` is new call to the script

Comment: How do you check for memory use?  A task monitor reports a memory usage for each running script.  The memory use of one script call shouldn't affect the use of another, regardless of whether it is running concurrently or sequentially.